# Issue with a C thread code that I am writing

Tags: c, multithreading, process, operating-system

I am writing a simple multithreading code which increments a variable in the called function of a thread. Creating threads using for loop and also want to print the looping variable i, in each thread.

Here is the snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 10

static int a = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mut;
pthread_mutex_t muti;

void *
dummy(void *data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    a++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    printf("In the dummy function.. thread %d \n", *(int *) data);
}

int
main()
{
    int ret;
    pthread_t array[N];

    pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&muti, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&muti);
        i++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&muti);

        ret = pthread_create(&array[i], NULL, &dummy, &i);

        if (ret != 0) {
            printf("Error with code %d.. \n", ret);
            return i;
        }

        printf(" a value is: %d\n", a);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pthread_join(array[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&muti);

    return 0;
}
```

**Here is the output of the same:**

```
a value is: 0
In the dummy function.. thread 1
a value is: 1
In the dummy function.. thread 3
a value is: 2
In the dummy function.. thread 4
a value is: 3
In the dummy function.. thread 5
a value is: 4
In the dummy function.. thread 5
a value is: 5
In the dummy function.. thread 7
a value is: 6
In the dummy function.. thread 8
a value is: 7
In the dummy function.. thread 8
a value is: 8
In the dummy function.. thread 9
a value is: 9
In the dummy function.. thread 10
```

the program is hanging at the end
expecting **a value to be printed first** before **in the dummy function**
Program to terminate properly

Comment: Your method of passing data to threads is completely wrong. You need to allocate an `int` for each tread (say, have `int thread_data[N];` in `main`). Then you won't need `muti` and won't need to increment `i` in a wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

In your first `for` loop, your `i++` is placed badly.

As you have it, you increment `i` before you *store* into `&array[i]` with the `pthread_create`

So, you are storing into `array[1]` on the first loop iteration.

`array[0]` is *never* set to anything.

So, when you access `array[0]` in the loop for `pthread_join`, you have UB (undefined behavior) and [probably] a segfault.

Move the `i++` to the increment part of the first `for` statement.

Change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&muti);
    i++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&muti);

    ret = pthread_create(&array[i], NULL, &dummy, &i);

    ...
}
```

Into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&muti);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&muti);

    ret = pthread_create(&array[i], NULL, &dummy, &i);

    ...
}
```

---

However, even with this fix, there is a race condition.

The `muti` mutex does *not* protect against this. Because *only* `main` increments `i`, the mutex is largely a no-op.

`i` can [still] be incremented faster than the subthreads fetch `data`.

Notice that in the output below, some threads report the *same* index value instead of unique ones:

```
 a value is: 0
 a value is: 0
In the dummy function.. thread 2
 a value is: 1
In the dummy function.. thread 3
In the dummy function.. thread 3
 a value is: 3
In the dummy function.. thread 4
 a value is: 4
In the dummy function.. thread 5
 a value is: 5
In the dummy function.. thread 6
 a value is: 6
In the dummy function.. thread 6
 a value is: 7
In the dummy function.. thread 8
 a value is: 8
In the dummy function.. thread 8
 a value is: 9
In the dummy function.. thread 9
```

---

To fix this, we can pass `i` to the threads *by value*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 10

static int a = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mut;
pthread_mutex_t muti;

void *
dummy(void *data)
{
    int i = (uintptr_t) data;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    a++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);

    printf("In the dummy function.. thread %d \n", i);
}

int
main()
{
    int ret;
    pthread_t array[N];

    pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&muti, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ret = pthread_create(&array[i], NULL, &dummy, (void *) (uintptr_t) i);

        if (ret != 0) {
            printf("Error with code %d.. \n", ret);
            return i;
        }

        printf(" a value is: %d\n", a);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pthread_join(array[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&muti);

    return 0;
}
```

Then, we get:

```
 a value is: 0
 a value is: 0
In the dummy function.. thread 1
In the dummy function.. thread 0
 a value is: 2
In the dummy function.. thread 2
 a value is: 3
In the dummy function.. thread 3
 a value is: 4
In the dummy function.. thread 4
 a value is: 5
In the dummy function.. thread 5
 a value is: 6
In the dummy function.. thread 6
In the dummy function.. thread 7
 a value is: 7
 a value is: 8
 a value is: 8
In the dummy function.. thread 9
In the dummy function.. thread 8
```

---

The above is a special case of a more general way to handle multithreading.

Personally, I prefer to create a `struct` that has *all* per-thread related data.

Let's consider a case where we have a large array of numbers and we wish to sum all the elements. We wish to do the summing in parallel, splitting up the work amongst several threads.

Below is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct task {
    pthread_t tid;                  // thread ID
    int i;                          // thread index

    int start;                      // starting index for values array
    int end;                        // last element + 1

    uint64_t sum;                   // sum of elements
};

#define NTASK 10
struct task tasklist[NTASK];        // list of threads

#define NVALUES     10000
int values[NVALUES];                // array of values to sum

#define NPER    (NVALUES / NTASK)   // number of values per thread

void *
dummy(void *data)
{
    struct task *task = data;

    printf("dummy%d: starting with range %d to %d\n",
        task->i,task->start,task->end - 1);

    uint64_t sum = 0;
    for (int i = task->start; i < task->end; ++i)
        sum += values[i];

    task->sum = sum;
    printf("dummy%d: partial sum %llu\n",task->i,sum);

    return (void *) 0;
}

int
main()
{
    int ret;

    // fill in array with some values
    for (int i = 0; i < NVALUES;  ++i)
        values[i] = rand() % 1000000;

    // start all tasks
    for (int i = 0; i < NTASK; i++) {
        struct task *task = &tasklist[i];

        task->i = i;

        // starting index into array
        int valindex = i * NPER;
        task->start = valindex;

        // get one past last element to process
        valindex += NPER;
        // handle special case for last task
        if (i == (NTASK - 1))
            valindex = NVALUES;
        task->end = valindex;

        ret = pthread_create(&task->tid, NULL, &dummy, task);

        if (ret != 0) {
            printf("Error with code %d.. \n", ret);
            return i;
        }
    }

    // wait for all threads to complete and calculate cumulative sum
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NTASK; i++) {
        struct task *task = &tasklist[i];
        pthread_join(task->tid,NULL);

        // add given thread's partial sum to total
        printf("main: dummy%d sum is %llu\n",i,task->sum);
        total += task->sum;
    }
    printf("main: TASK %llu\n",total);

    // calculate array sum for comparison/cross-check
    uint64_t expected = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NVALUES; ++i)
        expected += values[i];
    printf("main: MAIN %llu\n",expected);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of that program:

```
dummy0: starting with range 0 to 999
dummy0: partial sum 492137495
dummy4: starting with range 4000 to 4999
dummy4: partial sum 497575491
dummy2: starting with range 2000 to 2999
dummy7: starting with range 7000 to 7999
dummy7: partial sum 496783511
dummy3: starting with range 3000 to 3999
dummy8: starting with range 8000 to 8999
dummy6: starting with range 6000 to 6999
main: dummy0 sum is 492137495
dummy9: starting with range 9000 to 9999
dummy9: partial sum 504435723
dummy3: partial sum 502991920
dummy8: partial sum 508750003
dummy2: partial sum 501006778
dummy5: starting with range 5000 to 5999
dummy6: partial sum 506369686
dummy1: starting with range 1000 to 1999
dummy5: partial sum 492532431
dummy1: partial sum 493532173
main: dummy1 sum is 493532173
main: dummy2 sum is 501006778
main: dummy3 sum is 502991920
main: dummy4 sum is 497575491
main: dummy5 sum is 492532431
main: dummy6 sum is 506369686
main: dummy7 sum is 496783511
main: dummy8 sum is 508750003
main: dummy9 sum is 504435723
main: TASK 4996115211
main: MAIN 4996115211
```